# image positioning with css in ie7 and ie6

Tags: css

I'm trying to position all images on my webpage behind a log-in screen but I can't seem to make that work. I've tried using z-index but that doesn't help either. I was wondering if anyone can help me sort this out. Here's a screenshot of my issue: http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/1267/uplad.png. I'm trying to make all images stay behind the black image with the log-in screen in front of everything.

**CSS**

CSS for images

```
img
{

    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

CSS for black background

```
element.style {

    height: 1843px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 1263px;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.modalBackground {

    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

CSS for Log-in Screen

```
element.style {

    display: block;
    margin-left: -225px;
    margin-top: -212px;
}

.pagepopups .popup {

    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #333333;
    background-color: #006699;
    display: none;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 11px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10001;
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant CSS and HTML.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've posted the css. there is too much html to post and there's alot of C# code as well

Comment: I figured it out thanks. if you want to know the solution let me know and i'll post it here

Comment: Oh darn. Was it what I just posted by any chance?

Comment: Double darn. I just wasted 5 minutes debugging this and you've already solved it :)

Comment: @Drackir: Yes, it was the issue you mentioned in your answer. I found the specifics.

Comment: Well at least the OP got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z-index does appear to be what you want. There is a known z-index bug with Internet Explorer where it doesn't exactly follow the z-index as other browsers. Fortunately, there's an easy fix. You need to specify z-index on parent elements up until the container for all of the elements you're trying to specify a z-index for. I think the problem is that IE creates a "z-index context" for each element unless the parent element has a z-index. [Here's](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) a good link describing the issue and how to fix it.

Comment: This helps alot i'm starting to see how z-index really works in IE. Thanks

Comment: @Zeeshan Raja: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Keep this in mind if you're having other z-index issues.

Answer (score 1):

You failed to make the image fully anonymous (*Featured on ..* button), I Googled for the live site, and it has the issue you're describing, so I'm assuming it's the same version you're working with.

Testing only in IE7:

- Add to `.header` a single rule: `z-index: 10000`.
- That's it fixed in IE7.
- It will probably also be fixed in IE6, but if not, let me know and I'll take a look.

You're lucky you didn't anonymise it properly :)

Comment: I fixed the issue but now i'm having issues with other popUps like the log-in screen